# In R - finding smallest number of cells creating groups smaller than n

Tags: r, performance, group-by, categorical-data

I have a data frame with several categorical columns, with differing number of unique entries.
When I group_by and summarise over all the columns together, there are groups smaller than n, where n is e.g. 2.
For example:

```
> df
   A B  C
1  x z a1
2  x z a2
3  x z a1
4  x w a1
5  x w a2
6  y w a1
7  y u a2
8  y u a2
9  y u a1
10 y u a1

DF = df %>% group_by_at(c(1:3)) %>% count()

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   A, B, C [7]
  A     B     C         n
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 x     w     a1        1
2 x     w     a2        1
3 x     z     a1        2
4 x     z     a2        1
5 y     u     a1        2
6 y     u     a2        2
7 y     w     a1        1
```

What is the most efficient way to find which cells have created the groups smaller than n, and to replace their value with one unified value, lets say "other", so that the smallest group created in the process would be of size n?
I need to do this process for much larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to tackle that, for example you could only replace all w's and z's in `B` with other. The simplest and fastest solution I could think of is probably using `data.table`, but whether this approach makes sense depends on your application.

```
df = structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("u", "w", "z"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a1", "a2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
library(data.table)
mingroup=2
setDT(df)[,n:=.N,.(A,B,C)][n<mingroup,c('A','B','C'):='other']
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C n
 1:     x     z    a1 2
 2: other other other 1
 3:     x     z    a1 2
 4: other other other 1
 5: other other other 1
 6: other other other 1
 7:     y     u    a2 2
 8:     y     u    a2 2
 9:     y     u    a1 2
10:     y     u    a1 2
```

---

Alternative:

```
df = structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", "y"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("u", "w", "z"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a1", "a2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
df=setDT(df)
library(data.table)
mingroup=2
for(i in c('C','B','A'))
  df[,n:=.N,.(A,B,C)][n<mingroup,eval(i):='other'][,n:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
        A     B     C
 1:     x     z    a1
 2: other other other
 3:     x     z    a1
 4:     x     w other
 5:     x     w other
 6: other other other
 7:     y     u    a2
 8:     y     u    a2
 9:     y     u    a1
10:     y     u    a1
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, but I wonder if there is a systematic way to not put "other" on the whole row, but only on the part that is critical for creating the small group. For example, in rows 1 and 2, I could mark only "a1" and "a2" as "other", and the group would become of size 2.

Comment: Hi @Omry, I added an alternative that comes closer to what you may want. Hope that helps!